# Lost Ark save on update 7.37 how to recover for update 7.39

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network, ark-survival-evolved

Anyone who loaded their saves on September 1 after the update lost their saves. The issue was fixed September 2 in update 7.39. Is there a way to recover lost saves on Xbox once they are overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is maybe...
If you have loaded your save on a different Xbox then yes you can. If you access the 2nd Xbox and load your save offline or choose the older save when online, you can overwrite the corrupted save and recover your game pre 7.37 update, though the save file will be whenever you logged onto Ark on the second Xbox.